# Gathering Meta Data for a Data Catalog

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a data catalog for my company. We have a vast amount of databases spread out across different instances that all do different things for different groups within the company. Gathering the tables and where they were located was rather easy but my goal is to be able to say what placed the data there. Data enters the different tables in a number of ways such as through different services and SSIS packages and I'd like to find a way to gather this information in the background somehow.

I have looked at logon audit triggers and the idea of extended events but haven't found a solution.

Right now, I could manually go through and gather this meta data but it would take a log time and become quickly outdated and thus useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you didn't volunteer for this.

Extended events is probably your best bet. Use the system DMV's, specifically the two with referencing/referenced dependencies to see which procs insert into which tables. Then use the sql_modules table to find which triggers/functions insert into which tables, then run XE for like a year and capture all the DML statements and see which application/client is running the process for the insert.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your answer and will be giving it my best effort. I would give you a up vote but don't have the cred.